Flutter DevTools only ws are shown in the Network tab?
Flutter DevTools shows only internalAdress (websockets) although I need regular http queries with json data, it should come. Where the request passes correctly, the data is returned, it’s just that the type of request is not shown correctly in devtools
This problem appeared after the update
Flutter DevTools: 3.22.0 / stable
Dart Version: 3.4.0


I just rolled back to the version using flutter downgrade and everything works, which means the new version is still unstable

Be aware that this "ws" is not websocket: https://github.com/flutter/devtools/issues/3033

For tracking purpose : https://github.com/flutter/flutter-intellij/issues/7571
